# make: *** No rule to make target '.obj', needed by '.exe'. Stop

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, mingw-w64

I want to recompile an old Fortran 77 code (having a lot of subroutines) via gfortran in MingW bash platform in windows 10. There is a makefile among the old code files which is attached here:

---

```
Version = 2.10

FOR     = df
FFLAGS  = /optimize:5
INSTALL = move
DELETE  = del
COPY    = copy
#               these libraries must already exist somewhere
#               where ld can find them
LIBS    = \rfem\lib\GAF77.lib \rfem\lib\VFEM.lib DFPORT.lib
#               where the final program is to be placed
BINDIR  = \rfem\bin
#               where the cat man pages are to go
CATDIR  = \rfem\doc

# here are the files needed to construct Rslope2D

FILES = mrslope2d.f \
chknxe.f  dismsh.f  echosd.f fem2det.f fem2rf.f \
fem2sd.f  feminit.f mesh.f   openin.f  opensd.f \
pltfld.f  readsd.f  rect.f   setsd2.f  sim2sd.f \
statsd.f  szchk.f   vecmsh.f

OBJS  = mrslope2d.obj \
chknxe.obj  dismsh.obj  echosd.obj fem2det.obj fem2rf.obj \
fem2sd.obj  feminit.obj mesh.obj   openin.obj  opensd.obj \
pltfld.obj  readsd.obj  rect.obj   setsd2.obj  sim2sd.obj \
statsd.obj  szchk.obj   vecmsh.obj

rslope2d.exe: $(OBJS)
link /out:rslope2d.exe $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
$(DELETE) $(BINDIR)\rslope2d.exe
$(INSTALL) rslope2d.exe $(BINDIR)
$(COPY) rslope2d.1 $(CATDIR)

clean:
$(DELETE) *.obj
```

---

After navigating to the directory where this makefile is located and typing make in the MingW window (to recompile the main code),
I encounter the following error:

```
  No rule to make target 'mrslope2d.obj', needed by 'rslope2d.exe'.  Stop.
```

I am a beginner in Fortran, so apologies if the question is simple.

Looking forward to your suggestions and guidance as I do not know how to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Please be sure to include the correct indentation in your example: this is a syntax error for GNU make as you've shown it here.  However your problem is you've defined a rule telling make how to link object files into a final executable but you have no rule defining how to compile a Fortran source file into an object file.  So make tells you it doesn't know how to build the object file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, how should I define such a rule to compile a Fortran source file into object file? could you please elaborate a bit more? is there any guidance?  and also how should the indentations be in Fortran 77 Makefile?

Comment: [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction).

Comment: I'm not really versed in Fortran, and definitely not on Windows.  So I can't really help you.  You need to figure out what the Fortran compiler command line is on your system.  Once you know what command to type from your shell prompt to compile Fortran files, then we can help you create a rule in your makefile that invokes that command.